# How to Prove/Disprove the reliability of data in excel and google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

How can I Prove/Disprove the reliability of data in excel and google sheets? Attached image is the data I want to prove/disprove

***Sample Data***

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly are you trying to "prove or disprove"? Are you trying to see if the extracted dates in Column B match the string dates in Column A for each row? If the weekday matches the date? And once you "prove or disprove," then what should happen? Do you want to highlight any that don't match? Or do you want to have another column (like Column C) that shows an "X" if it doesn't match. You need to give more detail and to clearly show the result you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can below formula in desktop excel-

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),{3,2,6}))),"mmm dd yyyy")
```

[image]

And this formula to `google-sheet`

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXT(DATEVALUE(TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",100)),{2,1,5}*100,100)))),"mmm dd yyyy"))
```

[image]